# Why is ByteArray() combining array values? (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, hex, byte, ascii

```
>>> bytearray([2,88])
bytearray(b'\x02X')
```

Why is bytearray() combining them? And why is it turning 88 into ascii (X)? I was expecting two separate values, and 88 to convert to hex (x58)

```
bytearray(b'\x02,x58)
```

Answer (score 1):

Because ASCII 88 (capital letter X) is printable, and the behavior of `bytes.str()` / `bytes.repr()` is to not encode printable characters.

Just try to print `bytearray(range(256))` and you'll see that there is a range of printable characters (from `\x20` to `\x7e`) which do not get displayed as `\x##`.

Nonetheless, you can input `\x58` in a byte sequence, but it will again be displayed as `X`:

```
>>> b'\x58'
b'X'
```

Here's a little trick to print all values encoded to `\x##` form:

```
>>> b = bytearray([2,88])
>>> print(''.join('\\x%02x'%x for x in b))
\x02\x58
```

Comment: Ah okay, thanks. So is there a way to take an array:

arr = [2,88]

and have it turn into:

bytearray(b'\x02,x58)

using bytearray somehow?